# ArrayList.clear() is updating previous values of List<>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am getting `JSONArray` from server. The `JSON` I am getting has the following format.

```
[ {
   "area_name":"abc",
   "coordinates":[
     {
     "lat":1.123,
     "lng":2.123,
     },
     {
     "lat":1.123,
     "lng":2.123,
     },
     .
     .
     ]
},
{
.
.
.
}
]
```

In order to plot the areas on map I am adding areas to `areaList` and their corresponding coordinate in `coordinatesList`

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>> coordinatesList; // initialised in onCreate
List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>>> areaList; // initialised in onCreate

for (int i = 0; i < areaArray.size(); i++) {
     coordinatesList.clear();
     //coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
     //  parsing of json and other non-related stuff

      for (int j =0; j < pointsArray.size(); j++) {
          // Getting data from json and saving to hashmap and adding to coordinatesList
          coordinatesList.add(pointsHashMap);
     }

     areaList.add(coordinatesList);
}
```

Now if I try to get values from this `areaList` at a certain function. I get the same values for all position.

```
log.d(TAG, "area " + areaList.get(i).get(0).get("lat_lng)); // its in a loop
```

for any value of `i` I get the last added value by `areaList.add(coordinatesList);`. All the previously added values in the `areaList` are replaced.

But when I comment `coordinatesList.clear();` and uncomment `coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();` everything works as expected.

Can someone please elaborate this, why is it happening like this?

Comment: Adding an item into an array list doesn't copy it. You are adding the same list over and over. Just declare coordinatesList inside the loop; create a new one each iteration.

Comment: well, ah, that was pretty silly of me. I think working whole night is taking its toll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to add a new ArrayList to areaList each iteration through the loop.  Right now you're adding the same instance of coordinatesList to areaList each time through the loop.  That same instance is getting cleared at the top of the list.

*Adding the same coordinatesList to the areaList doesn't copy the elements, it merely adds the reference to the existing list.*

Answer (score 5):

because every time  you insatiate the arraylist in loop try to insatiate arraylist in **onCreate();**

```
coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Yes; but it would be better to declare it as a local variable, so you are not left with the contents from the last iteration after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 2):

As this is initialised in our `onCreate` method, which will be called once the activity is pushed to backstack. `ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>> coordinatesList;` 
 Now the instance of your coordinatesList is valid throughout your `Class`/`Activity`. 
So if you want to get new results all the time while invoking your function for coordinatesList implementation, either you need to reinitialize the `ArrayList` object or clear it to get new results poplated.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super(b);

    parseResponse();
}

private final void parseResponse(){

    areaList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>>>>(jsonArray.length());
    for(int i=0;i<areaList.size();i++){

        List<HashMap<String,LatLng>> coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        //  parsing of json and other non-related stuff

        for (int j =0; j < pointsArray.size(); j++) {
            // Getting data from json and saving to hashmap and adding to coordinatesList
            coordinatesList.add(pointsHashMap);
        }

     areaList.set(i,coordinatesList);
}
```

**Note:** The length of the JSON Array is the same as the length of `areaList` so we can initialize `areaList` to the same length when parsing. This can be more efficient then initializing a default-sized `ArrayList`

**Code Review:**

This snippet of code is rather unreadable:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>> coordinatesList; 
List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, LatLng>>> areaList;
```

I think it would be a lot cleaner if you declared an `Area` class that encapsulated the pertinent details. For example:

```
public class Area{
   private String name;
   private List<LatLng> coordinates; 

   public Area(String name, List<LatLng> coordinates){//...}
}
```

This would then reduce the code in your Activity to:

```
List<Area> areaList; 

private final void parseResponse(){

    areaList = new ArrayList<Area>(jsonArray.length());
    for(int i=0;i<areaList.size();i++){

        List<LatLng> coordinatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        //  parsing of json and other non-related stuff
        // Getting area_name and coordinates from json

         areaList.add(new Area(areaName,coordinatesList));
    }

}
```